# How can i make my own SDK by using com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision SDK

Tags: kotlin-android-extensions

I am setting up my own SDK in which `com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision` SDK is used .

First my SDK was not able to build successful when below line was added in my app build.gradle

apply plugin: `com.google.gms.google-services`

when i have removed this line SDK was successfully build.
I have integrated that SDK with my sample application but now getting below mentioned error :

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not
>   initialized in this process com.example.barcodescan. Make sure to call
>   FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.

I have called this method but then also it gives me same error.

Comment: hi @rinky can you post the code causing this issue?

Comment: hi @LuckyLikey while syncing my project this error comes.
It says call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) before calling  FirebaseVision.getInstance().getVisionBarcodeDetector(options).

Comment: I see you propably have some dependencies set up. If you provide a [mcve] it might help to understand your problem.